# convert decimal numbers to excess-127 representations

Tags: binary

Represent the following decimal numbers in binary using 8-bit signed magnitude, one’s complement, two’s complement, and excess-127 representations.

a) 77

b) –42

c)  119

d)  –107

I've converted them to the other representations just need to know how to convert to excess-127

a) Signed magnitude: 01001101 
One's complement: 01001101
Two's complement: 01001101

b) Signed magnitude: 10101010
One's complement: 11010101 
Two's complement: 11010110

c) Signed magnitude: 01110111 
One's complement: 01110111 
Two's complement: 01110111

please help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question does not make a lot of sense to me: What is input, what is output? What conversion method? Please add some more explanation to your post.

Comment: Represent the following decimal numbers in binary using 8-bit signed magnitude, one’s complement, two’s complement, and excess-127 representations.
a) 77
b) –42
c)  119
d)  –107

as you can see i got all the other ones, just need help with excess-127

Comment: @hotzst can you help?

Comment: Isn't excess-127 just adding 127 to the original number modulo 256, then just writing that as binary? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to Offset binary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary, of which the most famous example would be Excess-3: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excess-3, then the solution would be:

- a) 77 + 127 mod 256 = 204 mod 256 = 204 = 11001100
- b) -42 + 127 mod 256 = 85 mod 256 = 85 = 01010101

etc...

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you're doing exercise 16 from chapter 2 of The Essentials of Computer Organization and Architecture, 4th Edition. The text actually explains the concept quite simply in section 2.4.3, Excess-M Representation for Signed Numbers.

"The unsigned binary value for a signed integer using excess-M representation is determined simply by adding M to that integer."

So, for 77, you'd add M (127 in this case) to 77, giving you 204. COnvert that to binary and you get 11001100.

The rest should be easy to complete using the above method without asking the community to do your homework for you.